# Update the cart price, with a jQuery calculated price in Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am using the following Javascript/JQuery code to calculates a price based on measurements that the user inputs:

```
var linearM2was = ".002";
var linear2M2was = ".004";
var linear3M2was = ".006";


var linearM2 = ".001";
var linear2M2 = ".002";
var linear3M2 = ".003";


function calculateAreaMultipleDesktopLin() {
ga('send', 'event', 'instantPrice', 'gotInstantPrice', 'gotInstantPriceDayNightDesktop');
 var width = +document.getElementById("widthD").value;
    document.cookie = "blindWidth="+width+"; path=/";
 var height = +document.getElementById("heightD").value;
    document.cookie = "blindHeight="+height+"; path=/";
 if(document.getElementById("LMMD").checked) {
    if(width < "200"){document.getElementById("sizeCorrectionWidth").innerHTML = "min width 200mm";return false;}
    else if (width > "2400"){document.getElementById("sizeCorrectionWidth").innerHTML = "max width 2400mm";return false;}
    if(height < "600"){document.getElementById("sizeCorrectionHeight").innerHTML = "min height 600mm";return false;}
    else if (height > "3000"){document.getElementById("sizeCorrectionHeight").innerHTML = "max height 3000mm";return false;}
    var mmDevidetoM = "77";
    var mmWidth = width / mmDevidetoM;
    var mmHeight = height;
    var m2 = mmWidth * mmHeight;
     var measurmentType = "MM"; 
    document.cookie = "blindMeasurement=mm; path=/"; 
 }
 else if(document.getElementById("LCMD").checked) {
    if(width < "20"){document.getElementById("sizeCorrectionWidth").innerHTML = "min width 20cm";return false;}
    else if (width > "240"){document.getElementById("sizeCorrectionWidth").innerHTML = "max width 240cm";return false;}
    if(height < "60"){document.getElementById("sizeCorrectionHeight").innerHTML = "min height 60cm";return false;}
    else if (height > "300"){document.getElementById("sizeCorrectionHeight").innerHTML = "max height 300cm";return false;}
    var cmDevidetoM = ".77";
    var cmWidth = width / cmDevidetoM;
    var cmHeight = height;
    var m2 = cmWidth * cmHeight;
    var measurmentType = "CM"; 
    document.cookie = "blindMeasurement=cm; path=/"; 
 }
 else if(document.getElementById("LINCHESD").checked) {
    if(width < "7.87402"){document.getElementById("sizeCorrectionWidth").innerHTML = "min width 7.87inches";return false;}
    else if (width > "94.48819"){document.getElementById("sizeCorrectionWidth").innerHTML = "max width 94.48inches";return false;}
    if(height < "23.622"){document.getElementById("sizeCorrectionHeight").innerHTML = "min height 23.62inches";return false;}
    else if (height > "118.1102"){document.getElementById("sizeCorrectionHeight").innerHTML = "max height 118.11inches";return false;}
    var inDevidetoM = "3.0315";
    var inWidth = width / inDevidetoM;
    var inHeight = height / inDevidetoM;
    var m2 = inWidth * inHeight;
    var measurmentType = "INCHES"; 
    document.cookie = "blindMeasurement=in; path=/"; 
 }



 var priceTotal = m2 * linearM2;
 var priceTotal2 = m2 * linear2M2;
 var priceTotal3 = m2 * linear3M2;


 var priceTotalWas = m2 * linearM2was;
 var priceTotal2was = m2 * linear2M2was;
 var priceTotal3was = m2 * linear3M2was;


 var priceTotalMSupply = priceTotal - (priceTotal * 0.2);
 var priceTotal2ndTierMSupply = priceTotal2 - (priceTotal2 * 0.2);
 var priceTotal3rdTierMSupply = priceTotal3 - (priceTotal3 * 0.2);


 var priceTotalWasMSupply = priceTotalWas - (priceTotalWas * 0.2);
 var priceTotal2ndTierWasSupply = priceTotal2was - (priceTotal2was * 0.2);
 var priceTotal3rdTierWasSupply = priceTotal3was - (priceTotal3was * 0.2);


document.getElementById("priceCheckButtonDesktopLin").innerHTML = "GET ANOTHER INSTANT PRICE";
document.getElementById("resultMultipleDesktop").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("widthD").value = "";
document.getElementById("heightD").value = "";

var mybr = "<span class='vc_col-sm-12' id='resultMultipleDesktop4' style='text-align: left;'><span class='vc_col-sm-4 pCheckHeader1'>PREMIER COLLECTION</span><span class='vc_col-sm-4 pCheckHeader2'>FULLY FITTED PRICE <span>£" + priceTotal.toFixed(2) + "</span></span><span class='vc_col-sm-4 pCheckHeader3'>DIRECT PRICE <span>£" + priceTotalMSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></span></span><span class='vc_col-sm-3' id='resultMultipleDesktop1'><span class='priceBackContainer'><span class='priceBack'><img class='imagePaddingLookup' src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Premier-View-Black-HERO-600x340.jpg' width='350px'>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotalWas.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>FULLY FITTED <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/home/'><span class='viewHereStyle'>book here</span></a></span></span></span><br><hr>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotalWasMSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>SHADES DIRECT <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotalMSupply.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/product/premier-day-and-night-blind-black/'><span class='buyNowStyle'>buy now</span></a></span></span></span><br></span><span class='vc_col-sm-3' id='resultMultipleDesktop1'><span class='priceBackContainer'><span class='priceBack'><img class='imagePaddingLookup' src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Premier-View-Porcelain-HERO-600x340.jpg' width='350px'>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotalWas.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>FULLY FITTED <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/home/'><span class='viewHereStyle'>book here</span></a></span></span></span><br><hr>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotalWasMSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>SHADES DIRECT<span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotalMSupply.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/product/premier-day-and-night-blind-porcelain/'><span class='buyNowStyle'>buy now</span></a></span></span></span><br></span><span class='vc_col-sm-3' id='resultMultipleDesktop1'><span class='priceBackContainer'><span class='priceBack'><img class='imagePaddingLookup' src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Premier-View-Silver-HERO-600x340.jpg' width='350px'>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotalWas.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>FULLY FITTED <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/home/'><span class='viewHereStyle'>book here</span></a></span></span></span><br><hr>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotalWasMSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>SHADES DIRECT <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotalMSupply.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/product/premier-day-and-night-blind-silver/'><span class='buyNowStyle'>buy now</span></a></span></span></span><br></span><span class='vc_col-sm-3' id='resultMultipleDesktop1'><span class='priceBackContainer'><span class='priceBack'><img class='imagePaddingLookup' src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Premier-View-White-HERO-1-600x340.jpg' width='350px'>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotalWas.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>FULLY FITTED <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/home/'><span class='viewHereStyle'>book here</span></a></span></span></span><br><hr>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotalWasMSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>SHADES DIRECT<span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotalMSupply.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/product/premier-day-and-night-blind-white/'><span class='buyNowStyle'>buy now</span></a></span></span></span><br></span><br><span class='vc_col-sm-12' id='resultMultipleDesktop4' style='text-align: left;'><span class='vc_col-sm-4 pCheckHeader1'>SIGNATURE COLLECTION</span><span class='vc_col-sm-4 pCheckHeader2'>FULLY FITTED PRICE <span>£" + priceTotal2.toFixed(2) + "</span></span><span class='vc_col-sm-4 pCheckHeader3'>DIRECT PRICE <span>£" + priceTotal2ndTierMSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></span></span><span class='vc_col-sm-3' id='resultMultipleDesktop1'><span class='priceBackContainer'><span class='priceBack'><img class='imagePaddingLookup' src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Seasons-Antractitic-Hero-600x340.jpg' width='350px'>From<strike><span style='color:#000;'> £" + priceTotal2was.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>FULLY FITTED <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal2.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/home/'><span class='viewHereStyle'>book here</span></a></span></span></span><hr>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotal2ndTierWasSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>SHADES DIRECT<span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal2ndTierMSupply.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/product/seasons-day-and-night-blind-antractic/'><span class='buyNowStyle'>buy now</span></a></span></span></span><br></span><span class='vc_col-sm-3' id='resultMultipleDesktop1'><span class='priceBackContainer'><span class='priceBack'><img class='imagePaddingLookup' src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Seasons-Grey-Hero-600x340.jpg' width='350px'>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotal2was.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>FULLY FITTED <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal2.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/home/'><span class='viewHereStyle'>book here</span></a></span></span></span><hr>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotal2ndTierWasSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>SHADES DIRECT <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal2ndTierMSupply.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/product/seasons-day-and-night-blind-grey/'><span class='buyNowStyle'>buy now</span></a></span></span></span><br></span><span class='vc_col-sm-3' id='resultMultipleDesktop1'><span class='priceBackContainer'><span class='priceBack'><img class='imagePaddingLookup' src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Seasons-Ice-White-HERO-600x340.jpg' width='350px'>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotal2was.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>FULLY FITTED <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal2.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/home/'><span class='viewHereStyle'>book here</span></a></span></span></span><hr>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotal2ndTierWasSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>SHADES DIRECT<span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal2ndTierMSupply.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/product/seasons-day-and-night-blind-ice-white/'><span class='buyNowStyle'>buy now</span></a></span></span></span><br></span><span class='vc_col-sm-3' id='resultMultipleDesktop1'><span class='priceBackContainer'><span class='priceBack'><img class='imagePaddingLookup' src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Seasons-Ivory-HERO-600x340.jpg' width='350px'>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotal2was.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>FULLY FITTED <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal2.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/home/'><span class='viewHereStyle'>book here</span></a></span></span></span><hr>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotal2ndTierWasSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>SHADES DIRECT<span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal2ndTierMSupply.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/product/seasons-day-and-night-blind-ivory/'><span class='buyNowStyle'>buy now</span></a></span></span></span><br></span><br><span class='vc_col-sm-12' id='resultMultipleDesktop4' style='text-align: left;'><span class='vc_col-sm-4 pCheckHeader1'>DESIGNER COLLECTION</span><span class='vc_col-sm-4 pCheckHeader2'>FULLY FITTED PRICE <span>£" + priceTotal3.toFixed(2) + "</span></span><span class='vc_col-sm-4 pCheckHeader3'>DIRECT PRICE <span>£" + priceTotal3rdTierMSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></span></span><span class='vc_col-sm-3' id='resultMultipleDesktop1'><span class='priceBackContainer'><span class='priceBack'><img class='imagePaddingLookup' src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Dixie-Grey-HERO-600x340.jpg' width='350px'>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotal3was.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>FULLY FITTED <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal3.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/home/'><span class='viewHereStyle'>book here</span></a></span></span></span><br><hr>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotal3rdTierWasSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>SHADES DIRECT<span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal3rdTierMSupply.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/product/dixie-day-and-night-blind-grey/'><span class='buyNowStyle'>buy now</span></a></span></span></span><br></span><span class='vc_col-sm-3' id='resultMultipleDesktop1'><span class='priceBackContainer'><span class='priceBack'><img class='imagePaddingLookup' src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Dixie-Ice-White-HERO-600x340.jpg' width='350px'>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotal3was.toFixed(2) + "</span> </strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>FULLY FITTED <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal3.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/home/'><span class='viewHereStyle'>book here</span></a></span></span></span><br><hr>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotal3rdTierWasSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>SHADES DIRECT <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal3rdTierMSupply.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/product/dixie-day-and-night-blind-ice-white/'><span class='buyNowStyle'>buy now</span></a></span></span></span><br></span><span class='vc_col-sm-3' id='resultMultipleDesktop1'><span class='priceBackContainer'><span class='priceBack'><img class='imagePaddingLookup' src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Dixie-Light-Grey-HERO-600x340.jpg' width='350px'>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotal3was.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>FULLY FITTED <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal3.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/home/'><span class='viewHereStyle'>book here</span></a></span></span></span><br><hr>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotal3rdTierWasSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>SHADES DIRECT<span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal3rdTierMSupply.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/product/dixie-day-and-night-blind-light-grey/'><span class='buyNowStyle'>buy now</span></a></span></span></span><br></span><span class='vc_col-sm-3' id='resultMultipleDesktop1'><span class='priceBackContainer'><span class='priceBack'><img class='imagePaddingLookup' src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Dixie-Ivory-HERO-600x340.jpg' width='350px'>From<strike><span> £"+ priceTotal3was.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>FULLY FITTED <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal3.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/home/'><span class='viewHereStyle'>book here</span></a></span></span></span><br><hr>From<strike><span> £" + priceTotal3rdTierWasSupply.toFixed(2) + "</span></strike> <span class='paddingWayFitSup'><br>SHADES DIRECT <span class='priceCheckColour'> £" + priceTotal3rdTierMSupply.toFixed(2) + "<a href='/product/dixie-day-and-night-blind-ivory/'><span class='buyNowStyle'>buy now</span></a></span></span></span><br></span><br><br><br>"; 
 (function($){
   $('#resultMultipleDesktop').html(mybr);
   $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#resultMultipleDesktop").offset().top
    }, 2000);
 }(jQuery));    
 }
```

The problem is Javscript/JQuery displays the calculated price, and then the user can select a button to take them to the product page, but the calculated price is not taken through to the actual product as this has its own price…

I want to be able to take through the custom price and make the product able to be added to the cart with the custom price instead of the default price, can this be done?

*(enter a width and height of 100 for example and then hit get instant price button, then click the buy now button and you will see the problem)*

The [link to the page](https://sb.shades-blinds.co.uk/areas/blinds-ayr/day-night-blinds-2).

Comment: you can increase the product quantity based on price

Comment: @vel Ummm i dont want to increase the product quantity?, i want to carry through the calculated price to overwrite the default product price ....